# MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: Case-insensitive properties were deprecated in 3.3

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, deprecation-warning

The entire section is code. Am unable to figure out the solution when adding stock symbols on Python, the same error message is released.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

I am new to coding and have been watching plenty of videos regarding it, so I hope that everything makes sense.

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

yf.pdr_override()
start =dt.datetime(2020,4,1)
now = dt.datetime.now()

stock = input("Enter the stock symbol : ")

while stock != "quit":

df = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, now)

df ["High"].plot(label="high")

pivots=[]
dates=[]
counter=0
lastPivot=0

Range=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
dateRange=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,]

for i in df.index:
    currentMax=max(Range, default=0)
    value=round(df["High"][i],2)

    Range=Range[1:9]
    Range.append(value)
    dateRange=dateRange[1:9]
    dateRange.append(i)

if currentMax==max(Range, default=0):
    counter+=1
else:
    counter=0
if counter==5:
    lastPivot=currentMax
    datloc=Range.index(lastPivot)
    lastDate=dateRange[dateloc]

    pivots.append(lastPivot)
    dates.append(lastDate)

print()


timeD=dt.timedelta(days=30)

for index in range(len(pivots)):
    print(str(pivots[index])+": "+str(dates[index]))

plt.plot_date([dates[index],dates[index]+timdD],
    [pivots[index],pivots[index]], linestyle="-", linewidth=2, marker=",")


plt.show()

stock = input("Enter the stock symbol : ")
```

Comment: you don't need to worry about the warning.

Comment: There is supposed to be a graph that shows up when the screen is run; however, nothing comes up.